# Setting JQuery's Autocomplete to suggest only on hitting enter

Tags: html, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to adjust the autocompletion to show me the suggestions only when I hit the enter button, not as I type.. How is this possible? 
I think it would be easy to edit the code in the JQuery file itself, but I am trying to avoid that, is there a way to alter functions or so? 
At this point, I'll need to make an Ajax call to get the data that shall be used as the 'source' of the autocomplation box, so I will need to change the source according to the response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set disabled = true when you assign the plugin

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ disabled: true });
```

and then enable on keypress I believe

```
$( ".selector" ).keypress(function(e){
 if(e.keyCode == 13){ // can't remember exact syntax or keycode here
   $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "enable" );
 }
});
```

more info is available on the options and methods tab on the ui help page
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-option

Comment: I added this to the initialization: `disabled: true`
and then added this
 `$('.selector').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){ // can't remember exact syntax or keycode here
   $(this).autocomplete( "option", "disabled", false );  
  }
 });`
it disables the suggestions until I hit enter yes, but then it waits for another character to be entered in order to give the suggestions, I want it to show the suggestions right away, then I will disable it again until enter is hit again.

Comment: `$( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "enable" ).autocomplete( "search" )` maybe this will help..it should trigger search..and you will need to disable again in close event. check the url which tommy posted

Comment: Yup, excellent, that's exactly how I want it, thanks :) a the end it looks like this:
`$('.selector').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){ 
   $(this).autocomplete( "enable" ).autocomplete( "search" );
   $(this).autocomplete( "disable" );
   // Here we remove the class that causes the suggestions restore opacity.
   $('.ui-autocomplete').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
   $('.ui-autocomplete').css('cursor','pointer');
  }
 });`

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, here's how it worked, thanks for Tommy and Jags 
first disable the the autocomplate in the initialization, by adding this option: `disabled: true`
Then add this listener:

```
$('.selector').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){ 
        $(this).autocomplete( "enable" ).autocomplete( "search" );
        $(this).autocomplete( "disable" );  
        $('.ui-autocomplete').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
        $('.ui-autocomplete').css('cursor','pointer');
    }
});
```